# Remove quantity of item in cart

Tags: magento2.3, cart

**The Problem**

I'm looking at removing a specific quantity of an item that I already know is within the cart. There are lots of guides explaining how to remove items completely from the cart but let's say I have an item in the cart with a quantity of 2 I just want to remove a quantity of 1 rather than the product itself.

Comment: You can update the product as per changed quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the item you want to change just do this:

```
$item->setQty(    $item->getQty() - $qtyToRemove);
```

if not you have to iterate throught the products in your cart, something like this should work:

```
foreach($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{ 
     if $item->getProduct()->getId() == your_productid)
     {
        $item->setQty(    $item->getQty() - $qtyToRemove);
     }
}
$this->_cart->save();
```

let me knwo if you need any further assistance :)

Comment: I had to save the cart in order for the above code to work but after that was added it works great. I will suggest an edit to the question to amend the extra line